# Android: Get an mp3 file and display it in the higher/lower voice

Tags: android, audio, streaming, sampling

Here is the code so far; it just displays the normal song:

```
package com.training.MediaPlay;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.training.MediaPlayer.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MediaPlay extends Activity {
    public int x;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        Button PlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button PauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        //   final String[]items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mnth_array);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.mnth_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int pos, long id) {
                if(pos == 0)
                    x = 1;
                else if(pos == 1)
                    x = 2;
                else if(pos == 2)
                    x = 3;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
                // Do Nothing               
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);

        PlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                switch (x) {
                    case 1:
                        try {

                            mp.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mp.start();
                        break;

                    case 2:


                        break;

                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                }

            }
        });

        PauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                switch (x) {
                    case 1:
                        mp.pause();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //audiotrack.pause();
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I convert each input stream to have the higher voice when I play it.
Is it about the sampling rate or amplitude or something else??

And how can I deal with the following code. How can I use it?

---

```
File mediafile = new File(mediaFilePath);
short[] audio = new short[(int) (mediafile.length()/2)];

// read in file and fill up audio[]

AudioTrack audiotrack = new AudioTrack(
                                // stream type
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                // frequency
                    11025,
                                // channel config.. mono, stereo, etc
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                // audio encoding
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                // length
                    audio.length,
                                // mode
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
                    );
```

Please help me find the way out.

Comment: Less code, less bagging and more explanation please. Higher voice lower voice? What do you display so far? Anything? I am too busy to read through your code. Give a quick explanation and remove redundant code, e.g. I don't want to care about a Play/Stop button. That has nothing to do with your question I think.

Comment: I want to get the mp3 file from the specific filepath and play it in the higher pitch. What's the process to do that?

Comment: okay..Now I got that to use the audiotrack( which I can specify the frequency rate) to play the music file, I have to convert mp3 file to PCM first. How can I convert??